# How to add line numbers to all lines in Google Prettify?

Tags: javascript, css, prettify

I am using prettify:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
  some code
</pre>
```

It works but the line number show every 5 lines and not for every line. I am using these files

```
<link href="../src/prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/prettify.js"></script>
```

Basically at the end of this page http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html you can see that I want, but I looked at that code and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The root cause is `list-style-type: none` in prettify.css:

```css
/* Specify class=linenums on a pre to get line numbering */
ol.linenums { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 } /* IE indents via margin-left */
li.L0,
li.L1,
li.L2,
li.L3,
li.L5,
li.L6,
li.L7,
li.L8 { list-style-type: none /* <<< THIS is the cause! */ }
/* Alternate shading for lines */
li.L1,
li.L3,
li.L5,
li.L7,
li.L9 { background: #eee }
```

You can either remove that rule or override it with:

```css
.linenums li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Comment: Ha ha, I spend hours last night, and I should have thought of that, though it seems that I must have removed it from that style sheet but I did not remove it from my global style. - Thanks

Comment: Why on earth is this the default?

Comment: Not sure when it started, but the copy of prettify I downloaded had a hard coded path to the css file on the CDN.  So even though I had modified my local copy it was ignoring it.

Comment: Yep, if you use this solution make sure you change the run_prettify.js function to use "./prettify.css" instead of "https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/prettify.css"

Answer (score 29):

### Solution

Instead of modifying the CSS you can simply add in a line of CSS to achieve the desired behavior:

```
<style>

    .prettyprint ol.linenums > li { list-style-type: decimal; }

</style>
```

### Example

A full example might have the code below. [View results via jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AgEjk/) or see below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.css" />

    <style>
        .prettyprint ol.linenums > li { list-style-type: decimal; }
    </style>

<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
 foo
 bar
 bis
 sed
 awk
 cat
</pre>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Changing the css is a little messy.

Comment: I agree. Non intrusive answers are prefered.

Comment: up voted as this solution worked for me whereas the accepted answer did not.

Comment: One may need to give left padding to ol to make line numbers visible

Answer (score 3):

I like having the alternating background colors, so did it this way:

```
/* White background color for all even-numbered lines */
li.L0,
li.L2,
li.L4,
li.L6,
li.L8  { background-color: #fff; }
/* Light-gray background color for all odd-numbered lines */
li.L1,
li.L3,
li.L5,
li.L7,
li.L9 { background-color: #eee; }
```