# Google Prettify: Line numbers won't show

Tags: javascript, html, css, prettify

For some reason, my line numbers won't show. Is this a known issue? Code coloring works fine. It's just the line numbers that won't show

**HTML**

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums"><code class="language-html">
    &lt;h1 class="test"&gt;This is a header&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph&lt;/p&gt;
</code></pre>
```

**Does anyone know what can cause this?**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399547/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-all-lines-in-google-prettify

Comment: I found that question as well, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It had to do with setting list item to display:inline-block. Removing that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you include run_prettify.js in your page, specifying parameters such as;
autoload, lang, and skin.

I did this and line numbers just came up!

Read more here
http://practicalseries.com/1001-webdevelopment/21-02-codefrag.html